# Post html data to python model and return result back to html

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, scikit-learn

I am working on an application where a chatbot asks users questions, takes their answers, runs their answers through a python sklearn model, and outputs the result.

I have an html/javascript/jquery file that has input fields with id='0', id='1',...,id='16'. I am trying to use these values as input to a python sklearn model and return the result back without refreshing the page. I have it setup so when the last chatbot answer is submitted the data from the page is all gotten by the answer id's. I want to post this data as input to a model and return the result of the model back and have the chatbot respond with this result.

**Python app.py:**

```
app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

app.route('/getdata', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def getdata(): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        print('getting data')
        return json['data']
    else: 
       return 'no data'
```

**Javascript**

```
    function endMessage() {
    var e0 = document.getElementById('1') 
    var e1 = document.getElementById('2')

    var data = [e0,e1] 
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST", 
        url:"/getdata", 
        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(response) { 
            console.log(response); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

When the last question is submitted, the function endMessage is triggered. This is where I am trying to have ajax make the POST request.

First of all, I cannot get the data to post. My flask app never prints 'getting data' so it never seems that ajax posted the data. Secondly, I am confused how I can take this data pass it to my python model function and send it back to the html file. In my javascript should I use ajax for a "GET" and have a flask function that POSTS to a different route the model results?

Comment: "When I go to the /getdata route it always displays 'no data'. " yeah, because a browser view is a GET request, and you've configured it to behave exactly that way.

Comment: In any case, if your JS function successfully posts data, you should be able to retrieve with `request.json` property in your view function, but you've not set a datatype to go along with your POST so I'm not sure, currently, whether it will be accessible in Python that way.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to javascript/jquery/frontend development. Is there a way to make a POST on that route stay there so when I GET it the data from the POST is there

Comment: I have print statements in the /getdata flask rout for when data is supposed to be posted but the data never seems to post. I have added the contenType as well

Comment: Mmm, that doesn't sound standard. But potentially you can add the data to the user session (This is just a dict that is available in all views). You will want to override the default Flask session, though, because it's super small. You'll need flask-session. If you overflow the base session, it simply doesn't store information, it won't warn you that you overflowed the storage. I just use a disk-based storage for sessions, no need for redis et al. If you don't want it.

Comment: Your AJAX is not attached to any event. Do you want this on a button click or something?

Comment: I have the ajax in a function that is called when the user hits enter

Comment: I will post a code snippet of this

Comment: Is the server logging the request in the terminal?

Comment: It is not logging it

Comment: Use F12 if you're on chrome and watch what's posted in the console. It could be anything. Have you imported JQuery? You'll have to do some debugging on your end

Comment: I think the problem is that the ajax request is not attached to anything. I have a function that is called when the last message is posted but simply putting the ajax request in the function does not seem to make it post